# Clear before writing new string using glutbitmapcharacter

Tags: opengl, glut

I am using the following function in my code. It prints the desired message on screen for any mode.The problem is when I call my function for 2nd time to print something new on window, it overwrites on previous message.How do I clear the previous thing I wrote before writing the new one?

```
void output(float r, float g, float b,int mode )
    {
      glColor3f( r, g, b );
      glRasterPos2f(25, 25);
      int len, i;

      char string1[50] = "Edit Mode Enabled";
      char string2[50] = "Edit Mode Disabled";
      char string3[50] = "Delete Mode Enabled";
      char string4[50] = "Delete Mode Disabled";
      char string[50];
      switch(mode)
      {
        case 1: strcpy(string,string1); break;
        case 2: strcpy(string,string2); break;
        case 3: strcpy(string,string3); break;
        case 4: strcpy(string,string4); break;
      }
    cout << string <<endl;
      len = (int)strlen(string);
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10, string[i]);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of copying strings, you can use a string array. `const char* strings[] = {"Edit Mode Enabled", "Edit Mode Disabled", ...}; const char* string = strings[mode];`

Comment: Yes, It works But I need to only clear the string, not the whole screen. I have some point plotted on screen which I don't want to clear by calling this function.

Comment: You can't clear just the text; after rendering the text, it becomes a pixel on an image, just like everything else. You'll have to redraw your entire scene (which is what most games do every frame anyway).